# Unity Ads install tracking

Tags: android, event-tracking, unityads

I am trying to add installs tracking with Unity Ads. But there is no official documentation how to do it. I suppose it's possible because i did it for other ad notworks such as AppLovin, AdColony and another. I found documentation only for iOS.

Does anyone know how to do id?

Answer (score 0):

Unity Ads makes install tracking available for advertisers, but not for publishers.

http://unityads.unity3d.com/help/advertising/sdk-install-tracking